# Is there a way to get user statistics from MoinMoin

Tags: wiki, moinmoin

I am a beginner with MoinMoin. I am looking for a way to capture some stats about users. Specifically, interested in knowing the top contributors, their edit frequency, etc. Is there a way to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the usual webserver log based stuff, you could look at moin's editlog and eventlog, there are some helpers in MoinMoin.log package.

moin has also some buildin "stats" stuff in MoinMoin.stats and some macros using that.

if you have questions, the #moin irc channel on freenode (be patient) or the moin-user mailing list is maybe quicker than stackoverflow.